# Returning JSON as a .json file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to get the following code to return as a json file instead of returning a Aspx file.
I have used similar code in PHP that works, however, I can not duplicate it in C#. I would like it to respond as a .json file.

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output, Formatting.Indented);
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        Response.Headers.Add("Expires"," Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
        Response.Headers.Add("Pragma.","no-cache");
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

The output is fine, I just want it to be recognized as a .json file.

Comment: Write it to a file. `System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"D:\path.txt", json);`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think he's looking to return the **page** with a content type of json, not actually write it to a file...could be mistaken though.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add `.json` to the list of managed file extensions? So `GET foo.json` hits the managed pipeline and .NET stack?

Comment: Exactly. I do not want it stored in a file. There will be heavy traffic, and I am afraid the txt file will get mixed up and send the wrong data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
// note the case
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

or even better:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

For what you seem to do, I'd recommend using an `IHttpHandler` instead of aspx page. You can even configure that one to have the json extension (although extension should not be that important). Here is an example:

```
public class CustomHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    // return true to reuse (cache server-side) the result 
    // for the same request parameters or false, otherwise 
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        // do with the response what you must
    }
```

and configure it in the web config:

```
<configuration>
    </system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
            <add verb="*" 
                 path="*.asmx" 
                 validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions" />
            <add verb="*" 
                 path="*_AppService.axd" 
                 validate="false" 
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions" />
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" 
                 path="ScriptResource.axd" 
                 type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions" validate="false" />
            <!-- your handler here: -->
            <add verb="GET" 
                 path="CustomHttpHandler.json" 
                 type="YourApp.CustomHttpHandler, YourApp" />
        </httpHandlers>
     </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can play with the verb to make the handle accessible to GET/POST or other request types, use `"*"` for all. The handler is accessible as "~/CustomHttpHandler.json" - note the json extension added (the original is .ashx). You still have to put the content type headers in the response though.

Answer (score 5):

To raise "File Download" dialog you should try `Content-disposition`, I don't know how it wil work with `json`, but it worked fine for me when I used it for `pdf`.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output, Formatting.Indented);
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"a.json\"");
Response.Headers.Add("Expires"," Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
Response.Headers.Add("Pragma.","no-cache");
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

And this is a link to msdn documentation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

Answer (score 2):

You can set the filename of the returned data using the "Content-Disposition" header.

See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
  FileName = "MyData.json",

  // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
  // the browser to try to show the file inline
  Inline = false,
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

Comment: Should work well for inline=false. With inline=true, some browsers (I'm looking at you, IE) seem to ignore the filename when you do a Ctrl-S.

Comment: Thanks, I can use this for a different portion of the system where they will download files in that manner